# Is there any statistics on processing time of printf statement?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

printf is often used across the board in embedded systems for many different reasons. Besides just moving characters to an output stream there is a process involved to convert numbers into a specified format and also a buffer that is filled up from which characters are transmitted to a terminal one at a time.

Among different conversions e.g integer to string, float to string e.t.c and the time taken to write characters into a buffer and for a character to leave the buffer, how long does each process take?

I understand that the answer really depends on what hardware system we are using, I just need rough figures from any real world example. I find the printf calls to be REALLY slow on any system and wonder why they are so slow at all.

Comment: Your title more or less asks "how slow is a printf statement", but the last sentence of your post says you want to know "why they are slow". These are two different questions, and you should edit your question (and title) to make clear which one you want an answer to.

Comment: All I know is that they are slow, in my case the soft core processor seems to get stuck waiting on buffer to empty and the program crashes. I want to understand how much time the different parts of a printf usually take so I can create a way to hardware accelerate that part in FPGA.

Comment: On many embedded systems, console output is via RS232, so printf runs at whatever speed the baudrate allows.

Comment: This is going to depend on the specific system and especially the c library implementation you are using. printf is as fast as the implementation you are using makes it.

Comment: printf is actually really efficent and fast, people have told me about the assembly and optimizations that go into it, and they are amazing.

Comment: The time it takes is dependent on the processor and available resources, please describe your actual problem, this question is too broad

Answer (score 2):

If the printf() output is going through a UART/serial port, the time taken for the UART to transmit characters will probably be the slowest part of the operation by far.  Converting floating point values to an ASCII string may also take significant time.

Comment: That really depends on the embedded system.  On some, `printf()` goes right to a *blocking* write.  On others there's a serial output buffer normally drained by interrupts or DMA which may cause `printf()` to block when full, or drop characters, or....

Answer (score 1):

Because of all the variables involved here, such as the system architecture, buffering, baud rate, etc, there is no blanket answer.

The best answer is that you should simply measure it. Record the system clock or another timer before and after the operation to determine how long it's taking. Experiment with the format and baud rate, etc if you need the operation to be faster.

Here's one trick that can speed things up considerably at the cost of complexity:

Use sprintf instead of printf and write to a buffer. Next, write one byte at a time from the buffer to the serial port. Do this every time the serial port is idle either from an interrupt or in your main loop. This way your code will not block while the serial port transmits.